# Difference between param type in F# function

Tags: f#

I have this type:

```
type Age = Age of int
```

Whats the difference between using the arg type like this:

```
fun (Age value) -> value // this returns an int
```

and this

```
fun (value: Age) -> value // this returns an Age
```

Answer (score 4):

You're confusing the matter by using the name `Age` for two different things - the name of a type, and a constructor name in a discriminated union.

This makes the situation slightly clearer:

```ml
type AgeType = Age of int

fun (Age value) -> value

fun (value: Age) -> value
```

Now, the second line is still valid, but the third is an error:

```markdown
The type 'Age' is not defined.
```

Now the valid way to write the third line is

```ml
fun (value: AgeType) -> value
```

And this reveals the difference between the lines you are asking about.

In this line:

```ml
fun (value: AgeType) -> value
```

`value: AgeType` is merely explicitly stating the type of `value` - it is an `AgeType`

In this line:

```ml
fun (Age value) -> value
```

`Age value` is a pattern (because [a parameter list can contain patterns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/functions/lambda-expressions-the-fun-keyword#remarks)), so you are *unwrapping* the value inside the argument that is passed to the function. That's why `value` is an int in this case.